# stretching only one axis with 9patch

Tags: android, image, nine-patch

So I have pictures I only want to stretch via the nine patch functionality along one axis like this one:

[image: sample image]

As you can see there's not a lot of room on the sides so I can't stretch along the x axis without it becoming noticeable.  Instead I'm programmatically setting the width to the appropriate size (with this portrait version) and using the indicated regions along the y axis to fit to screen.

The problem is I keep getting this log output on build.

> AAPT out(164205) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
>   AAPT out(8577269) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
>   AAPT err(164205): ERROR: 9-patch image C:\Users\Brandon Thompson\AndroidStudioProjects\TilePuzzler\app\src\main\res\drawable\star_trek_federation_emblem_land9patch.9.png malformed.
>   AAPT out(24044720) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
>   AAPT err(164205):        No marked region found along edge.
>   AAPT err(8577269): ERROR: 9-patch image C:\Users\Brandon Thompson\AndroidStudioProjects\TilePuzzler\app\src\main\res\drawable\star_wars_imperial_emblem_port9patch.9.png malformed.
>   AAPT err(164205):        Found along left edge.
>   AAPT err(24044720): ERROR: 9-patch image C:\Users\Brandon Thompson\AndroidStudioProjects\TilePuzzler\app\src\main\res\drawable\star_trek_federation_emblem_port9patch.9.png malformed.
>   AAPT err(8577269):        No marked region found along edge.
>   AAPT err(24044720):        No marked region found along edge.
>   AAPT err(8577269):        Found along top edge.
>   AAPT err(24044720):        Found along top edge.
>   AAPT out(22973825) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
>   AAPT err(22973825): ERROR: 9-patch image C:\Users\Brandon Thompson\AndroidStudioProjects\TilePuzzler\app\src\main\res\drawable\star_wars_imperial_emblem_land9patch.9.png malformed.
>   AAPT err(22973825):        No marked region found along edge.
>   AAPT err(22973825):        Found along left edge.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Crunching Cruncher star_wars_imperial_emblem_port9patch.9.png failed, see logs

This would seem to indicate that I *must* designate some of my unavailable area on the x axis, but I was under the impression that you could set it to stretch only what you wanted.  Was that impression in error or am I missing something else?  Would it be possible to simply designate the entire x axis to ensure uniform stretching?  Thanks.

Comment: Here's a nice online tool for drawing 9 patch images. http://draw9patch.com/#url=http://draw9patch.com/image/btn.png&top[]=25&top[]=50&right[]=25&right[]=50&bottom[]=25&bottom[]=50&left[]=25&left[]=50

Comment: I tried that tool, I'm fairly certain it was designed with simple low res images in mind.  It lags so badly with a high res image that its impossible to get it to do what you want.  The draw9patch tool that came with the sdk is far better.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out 9patch images insist on having some black marks in the left and top margins.  By drawing a line along the entire side I didn't want stretched in segments I ensured an even expansion.